# RabbitMQ consumer losing connection

Tags: java, spring, azure, rabbitmq

We are using *RabbitMQ 3.3.1*, *spring-amqp-1.3.1*, *spring-rabbit-1.3.1* in our project and we are getting following exception. Our environment is in *Azure* cloud and we are seeing that the *RabbitMQ* server is losing the connection with the consumers more often. Once we restart our *OSGI* consumer bundle, it works for some time and then same issue occurs. Any help/tips are appreciated.

> [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor2]|WARN|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|370-spring-rabbit-1.3.1.RELEASE|Consumer
>   raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory
>   supports it com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection
>   error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:715)[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:705)[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:568)[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)[:1.7.0_51]
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:131[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]
>   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:533[367:com.rabbitmq.client:3.2.4]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your post to tweak the formatting. [Here is some info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future reference regarding formatting in the editor.

Comment: Do you have a *heartbeat interval* set? Do you have re-connecting handling in place?

Comment: did you resolve this problem?